# Ruby on Rails Excel file formula calculate without any manual interaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, ruby, selenium-webdriver, xssf

Am trying to use selenium webdriver in ruby on rails for import test case but most of my Excel file has "=Now()" formula so when without open and save that file manually i try to import it showing old date only

Actually am unable to use below mentioned logic in ROR

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook)
```